# Highlight times up to 20 mins earlier than current time in list

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, time, compare

I have a table with bus times in it, and I want to highlight the next time that's within 20 mins.

Each bus time is stored in a php variable, and I'm struggling to work out how to check through each one.

Here's the HTML/PHP:

```
<tr>
  <?php if(have_rows('departure_times')): while(have_rows('departure_times')): the_row();
  $stop_time = get_sub_field('time'); //This returns "H:i" ?>
    <td class="time">
      <span><?= $stop_time; ?></span>
    </td>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</tr>
```

That's a repeater, so it cycles through and creates a td for each 'stop time'.

Here's my current JS (not working):

```
var now = new Date.now();
var stop = new Date(' . $stop_time . ').getTime();
var slots = document.getElementsByClassName('time');

for(var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++){
  if ( stop < now ){
    slots[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to see if the stop if earlier than now in this example, for ease.

I feel like it's the new Date(' . $stop_time . ').getTime(); part which isn't working, and I don't know how to check what the output of that is - is it unix timestamp? I think it should be but I don't know for sure. And I don't know if I should be doing something different because of the php repeater - if var stop is an array, I get this isn't going to work!

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I feel like`...you don't need to feel it, you can debug and test it. What debugging have you done? Have you checked the values you're comparing against each other? Have you checked for console errors? `var stop = new Date(' . $stop_time . ').getTime();` doesn't appear to make sense, it's true. Are you attempting to combine JS and PHP there? If you want to inject a PHP value into a JS block, you need to actually open a PHP block and echo it, e.g. `var stop = new Date('<?php echo $stop_time; ?>').getTime();` could be what you needed there.

Comment: But if $stop_time is a variable containing a date in H:i format as per your comment, then you can't parse that using the JS Date constructor. And arguably you don't really need to - it's aready a time string. If you want to compare times though, without involving dates, you'd be well advised to use timestamps rather than values which are formatted for human readability...that way it's just a simple mathematical comparison rather than a string parsing exercise.

Comment: @ADyson Debug wasn't showing any error, but that'll be because it was just reading '.$stop_time.' as a string as you say. I've plugged in the php properly now and it works. I've got a weird discrepancy with the times though (it's thinking future times are in the past) but I think that's a timezone issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `var stop = new Date(' . $stop_time . ').getTime();` - that would only be _one_ specific stop time. But you output multiple _different_ ones in your table - and you want to compare "now" against each of those stop times.

Comment: @CBroe yeah that was definitely an issue. I'm running the script within each stop time loop now and it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

I was doing two things wrong:

1. Trying to run the script outside of the 'stop times' loop
2. Not inserting the 'stop time' php properly

Here's the working code:

```
<?php if(have_rows('departure_times')): while(have_rows('departure_times')): the_row(); $stop_time = get_sub_field('time'); ?>
  <td class="time">
    <span>
      <script>
      var now = new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000; //Add extra hour for BST
      var stop = '<?= strtotime($stop_time); ?>000'; //Add the missing millisecond digits
      var mins = 20 * 60 * 1000; //Mins in milliseconds
      if(stop >= (now - mins) && stop <= now){
        document.write('<i class="soon"></i>');
      }
      </script>
      <?php echo $stop_time; ?>
    </span>
  </td>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```